# Activity destroy timeout for HistoryRecord

Tags: android, android-activity, webview

I able to process half the items I have in a ginormous string but I am losing half my data.

Here is my log cat errors.

```
12-08 15:03:44.011: W/ActivityManager(59): Launch timeout has expired, giving up wake lock!

12-08 14:40:49.528: W/ActivityManager(59): Activity destroy timeout for HistoryRecord{4501c938 package.data/.class1

12-08 14:40:44.318: W/ActivityManager(59): Activity idle timeout for HistoryRecord{450204b8 package.data/.class2
```

Here is what I did, I placed method(which consist of a new bufferReader(new inputstream(String), 8 *1024) in a while loop. The main reason for this is because I am manipulating the string and changing its info on the fly.So in summary I am losing half data but I am able to show half of them. I want to be able to show the remaining.

I understand that this post is similar to other stuff but it seems different. If anyone can assist me in anyway i would be most appreciated.

Comment: I fixed up the warnings what the problem was how I placed in my variables which displays those 3 warnings on Logcat. It must be something with Displayed activity package.data/.class2: 8030 ms (total 8030 ms). Sorry for being the boy crying wolf.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a minor problem with my looping that gave me different log cat errors which wasted a lot of my time.